# Exception in camel-stream component while streaming url

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using the camel-stream component for streaming results from a url.

```
from("direct:sample")
.to(String.format("stream:url?url=RAW(%s)", "http://sample-endpoint.org"))
.to("stream:out")
```

I'm Using the producer template to invoke the route. Using camel-stream 2.17.0 version.

Getting the following exception :

```
! java.net.ProtocolException: cannot write to a URLConnection if doOutput=false - call setDoOutput(true)
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1265) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
```

Any pointer's on what's causing the exception ?  Is it the right way to stream a url in camel-stream? Hope I'm not making any mistake with regard to that.

Comment: Ah can you try with 2.17.3 or 2.18.0 release

Comment: And what version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a little bug in camel-stream, and therefore I logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10534

You would need to wait for this fix, as there is no workaround currently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any tentative dates on when the fix could be released ?